# Count the number of duplicates between rows excel

Tags: excel-formula

I’m wondering if someone can tell me how to count the number of duplicates that occur between 2 rows in excel? I’ve read lots of posts about counting duplicates in general, but it’s not quite what I’m looking for.

In the below example, I want to indicate how many numbers are repeated from the previous row. For example, Row 1 has 3 numbers repeating from Row 2. Row 2 has 1 number repeating from Row 3. Row 3 has 2 numbers repeating from Row 4.  I don’t need to know what numbers or how many times each number was repeated, I just need to know how many occurrences of duplicates there are. Each number would be in its own cell. Is this even possible?

```
Row 1>  20  22  40  41  42  47    
Row 2>  3   37  40  41  47  49    
Row 3>  1   2   3   4   5   6    
Row 4>  2   5   17  20  25  30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIF() wrapped in a SUM() as an array formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:F2,A1:F1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Put the formula in the first desired output cell, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copy down.

[image]